# trackbar control in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I want to know about controlling a trackbar. I want to do a different thing when it is moved backwards and something else when moved forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the ValueChanged event.

```
TrackBar tb = new TrackBar();
tb.ValueChanged += (o, e) =>
{
   // do something based using tb.Value
};
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.valuechanged.aspx